# auctex: in-document emacs font style for latex macros and environments

Tags: emacs, auctex

Is it possible to define in the latex document also the auctex font for user macros and environments?  Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
\newcommand{\nothing}[1]{}
%% ;;; \nothing color red style italic
```

and now in the remainder of the document, a \nothing{hello} would have the *hello* be displayed in red italics in emacs.  [partial answer accepted below lacks color but has style.  thx.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution: With `font-latex` enabled, you can fontify your macros with a file variable:

```lisp
%%% eval: (font-latex-add-keywords '(("nothing" "{" )) 'italic-command)
```

You have to add this line manually at the end of your LaTeX document to the local variables, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\nothing{Test}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% eval: (font-latex-add-keywords '(("nothing" "{" )) 'italic-command)
%%% End:
```

> [image]

---

AUCTeX loads and activates `font-latex` by default, no further tweaking needed.  You can check this with <kbd>C-h v TeX-install-font-lock RET</kbd>:

> TeX-install-font-lock is a variable defined in `tex.el'.
>   Its value is
>   font-latex-setup
>
> Documentation: Function to call to install font lock support. Choose
>   `ignore' if you don't want AUCTeX to install support for font locking.

Comment: could you please add how to enable font-latex?  apropos font-latex is not that helpful.

Comment: @ivoWelch - I've edited my answer.  Which AUCTeX version do you have (`C-h v AUCTeX-version`)?  And how did you install it?

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question: Can one configure AUCTeX to automatically add some of these `%%% eval: <...>` lines along with the other variables it puts at the end of documents?

Comment: @PhilippImhof - Check the definition of `TeX-add-local-master` in `tex.el`.  You have to copy that function into your `.emacs` and tweak it then (untested).

Comment: @ArashEsbati Good idea, thanks. I might also add the necessary ´add-keywords` directly to my `.emacs` as it is for one or two macros I use in most of my work related documents.

Comment: @PhilippImhof - I would like to discourage you from doing that.  If you have macros which you use on a regular basis, put them into a package `mystuff.sty` and write some proper AUCTeX support `mystuff.el` for it.  Put `mystuff.el` in a directory (`C-h v TeX-style-private RET` is a good start) and AUCTeX loads that style each time you load your package.

Comment: @ArashEsbati oh, that 's a very good hint. I actually never thought of that.  Thanks

Comment: hi arash--tried to google your email address.  advice doesn't work in the current form for me.  I got auctex 11.88 prebuilt with Vincent Goulet's OSX emacs.  if I stick the lisp function into init.el or a LaTeX-mode-hook in init.el, I get 'Symbol's function definition is void: font-latex-add-keywords'.

Comment: @ivoWelch - You have to put that line at the end of your LaTeX document; I've edited my answer.

Comment: great.  now it works nicely.  thank you also, philipp.  will investigate common combinations of .el and .sty files next.